# pug - array output via each without commas

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I have this following pug array and let it execute in an each. The problem is the values are listed with commas. I want it without commas.
I could write the array in the each like `each x, y in {'value1': 'value2', ...}` but that isnt comfortable.

The current code:

```
-
  var starWars = {
    "people": [
      "Yoda",
      "Obi-Wan",
      "Anakin"
    ],
    "rank": [
      "master",
      "master",
      "knight"
    ]
  }
each person, rank in {starWars}
  p= person.people
  p= person.rank
```

Output:

```
Yoda,Obi-Wan,Anakin

master,master,knight
```

Comment: Where are you output-ing exactly? console.log, browser, somewhere else?

Comment: In the browser. Its just a part of a pug file that get render to a html file.

Comment: codepen example: http://codepen.io/phng/pen/wgoaar

Comment: What output is desired?

Comment: `Yoda Obi-Wan Anakin

master master knight`

without the commas like in the output in the opening post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `=` character after the tag `p` is for [buffered code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#buffered-code). Any JavaScript expression is valid input and will be converted to a string before being printed.
So when you put in an array, it is converted to the string representation of that array which is to separate each element with a comma.

Add a `.join(" ")` after each array to convert them to a string yourself and delimit them by space rather than comma:

```
each person, rank in {starWars}
  p= person.people.join(" ")
  p= person.rank.join(" ")
```

Output with my changes:

```
Yoda Obi-Wan Anakin
master master knight
```